# Floating ul's li not staying inline when resizing the window

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm trying to convert what used to be a table based layout tabs. The layout appears to be working except in IE7+9 (not tried 8) when you resize the window and make it narrower than the tabs it then shifts them below rather than keeping them all on the same row and displaying a scrollbar. In ff9 it works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
/******************************************
User Control Panel
******************************************/
    .userCtrlPanel{
        float:right;
    }
/******************************************
Navbar
*******************************************/
    .navbar{
        clear:both;
    }
    .navbar ul{
        list-style:none;
        float:right;
        margin:0px;
    }
    .navbar ul li{
        float:left; 
        /*border:1px green solid;*/
        padding-left:15px;

    }
    ul.navbar li a{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
/*Current Tab */
    .currentTab{
        background-image:url(StandardTabCurrentRight.gif);
        /*border:1px solid red;*/
        background-position:right;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        padding-right:12px;
        padding-top:2px;
        /*color:#fff;*/
    }
    .currentTabLeft{
        background-image:url(StandardTabCurrentLeft.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        /*border:1px solid blue;*/
    }
    .currentTabRight{
        background-image: url(StandardTabCurrentBackground.gif);
    /*  border:1px solid purple;*/
    }
/*Non-current tab*/
    .nonCurrentTab{
        background-image:url(StandardTabNonCurrentRight.gif);
        /*border:1px solid red;*/
        background-position:right;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        padding-right:12px;
        padding-top:2px;
        /*color:#AAAAAA;*/
    }
    .nonCurrentTab:hover{
        color:blue;
    }
    .nonCurrentTabLeft{
        background-image:url(StandardTabNonCurrentLeft.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        /*border:1px solid blue;*/
    }
    .nonCurrentTabRight{
        background-image:url(StandardTabNonCurrentBackground.gif);
    /*  border:1px solid purple;*/
    }   
/*Horizontal Ruler*/
    .headerHR   {
        height:8px;
        background-image:url(ParentTabBase.gif);
        clear:right;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="userCtrlPanel">
        USERNAME
    </div>

<!--Tabs -->
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="currentTabLeft">
                <div class="currentTabRight">
                    <a href="#" class="currentTab">Home</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nonCurrentTabLeft">

                <div class="nonCurrentTabRight">
                    <a href="#" class="nonCurrentTab">Reports</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nonCurrentTabLeft">
                <div class="nonCurrentTabRight">
                    <a href="#" class="nonCurrentTab">Admin</a>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="headerHR"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

or a working copy here http://pastehtml.com/view/bl5bgt5le.html

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I tried using the code formatter but its not working. best view the demo.

Comment: fixed formatting. You can use {} icon to format a block of text:) - highlight text to be formatted and then click {}

Answer (score 0):

Just give your `.navbar` a relevant width and float it to the right, like so:

```
.navbar {
width:300px;
float:right;
}
```